# how to add Microsoft Edge browser on codecept.conf.js with protector

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge, codeceptjs, protector

I'm trying to run a test on multiple browsers : Edge, Safari, chrome , firefox

I'm using this configuration on codecept.conf.js with protector:

Protractor: {
      driver: 'hosted',
      browser: 'miscrosoftEdge',
      rootElement: 'body',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--lang:FR'] 
      },

But it returns this error : 
Error: Could not write to D:\ysance_global_JS\node_modules\selenium-standalone.selenium\edgedriver\17134-MicrosoftEdgeDriver.exe

Comment: You are passing the Chrome options in the code so it looks like you are testing with the MS Edge Chromium browser but if we see the error it looks like it is using the Microsoft web driver version 17134. this is for the MS Edge legacy browser. So if you are trying to make a test with the MS Edge Chromium browser then use the correct web driver for Edge Chromium. You can download it from here. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads Let me know if I misunderstand anything. I will correct myself.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes, I'm using Mc web driver version 17134. So, trying to delete it and replace it  under selenium-standalone folder , with correct webdriver , it dowloads the last version each time , so how can I force it to use the correct version.

Comment: it returns this failure:
Error: Could not write to D:\ysance_global_JS\node_modules\selenium-standalone\.selenium\edgedriver\17134-MicrosoftEdgeDriver.exe

Comment: at D:\ysance_global_JS\node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\install.js:204:38
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\install.js:384:9)
      at Request.onRequestResponse (node_modules\selenium-standalone\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether you are using the latest version of the MS Edge legacy browser? for example, Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 If yes, then you need to run this command in the command prompt to install the latest version of web driver. DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0 Try to provide more information about the version of the Edge browser you are using for this test. I will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: here is the version: Version 83.0.478.45

Comment: You are using the new MS Edge Chromium browser. You are using the incorrect web driver. You can download the correct version of the web driver from this link. https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/?prefix=83.0.478.45/ Make a test with this and let us know about your test results.

Comment: I've already dowloaded this version, and replace the old version manually by this one, but once I run the test, the olde version is dowloaded automatically and so the test fails .

Comment: I am not sure why you are using node_modules\selenium-standalone\lib\install.js Also, the code sample posted the original post not giving the idea why it is downloading the web driver for Edge legacy browser. I suggest trying to refer the steps from the Protractor official site. Ref: https://www.protractortest.org/#/